# Android GameActivity android_app->window is null after APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW

Tags: android, c++

Im using android NDK with android_native_app_glue to interface with my c++ code. Though I'm not getting a window back as I should?

```
void android_main(struct android_app *app)
{
  app->onAppCmd = handle_cmd;

  while (true)
  {
    // Read all pending events.
    int events;
    struct android_poll_source *source;

    // If not animating, block forever waiting for events.
    // If animating, loop until all events are read, then continue
    // to draw the next frame of animation.
    while ((ALooper_pollAll(0, nullptr, &events,
                            (void **)&source)) >= 0)
    {
        // Process this app cycle or inset change event.
        if (source)
        {
            source->process(source->app, source);
        }

        // ... // Other processing.

        // Check if app is exiting.
        if (app->destroyRequested)
        {
            // engine_term_display(&engine);
            return;
        }
    }
    // Process input events if there are any.
    // engine_handle_input(state);
  }
}


void handle_cmd(android_app *pApp, int32_t cmd)
{
    switch (cmd)
    {
    case APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW:
       // here pApp->window == NULL
       // and pApp->pendingWindow != NULL
```

**APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW**

> Command from main thread: a new ANativeWindow is ready for use. Upon
> receiving this command, android_app->window will contain the new
> window surface.

Why am I getting the APP_CMD_INIT_WINDOW cmd and still window is null?